# Вопрос по CGI - самодельная функция, как выцепить ID

Tags: html, веб-программирование, perl, cgi

Всем привет!
В общем есть Perl-скрипт, стандартная библиотека CGI там не используется, вместо этого написан велосипед:

```
sub init_cgi {
my $length = $ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH};
my $query = $ENV{QUERY_STRING};
$query =~ s/\0//g; 
$query =~ s/\.\.\///g;
$query =~ s/\|//g;
my (@assign);
if ($query){
@assign = split(/&/,$query);
$formlength = @assign;
}
elsif ($length) {
read(STDIN, $_, $length);
chomp;
@assign = split('&');
$formlength = @assign;
}
else {
$formlength = 0;
}
for (my $i=0; $i<$formlength; $i++) {
my ($name,$value) = split('=',$assign[$i]);
$value =~ tr/+/ /;
$value =~ s/%([a-fFA-F0-9][a-fFA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
$value =~ s/~!/ ~!/g;
$value =~ s/<!--(.|n)*-->//g;
if (defined($in{$name})) {
$in{$name} .= ",$value";
}
else {
$in{$name} = $value;
}
}
}
```

И есть HTML-код:

```
        <input id="star-4" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>
        <label title="Замечательно" for="star-4"></label>

        <input id="star-3" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>
        <label title="Хорошо" for="star-3"></label>

        <input id="star-2" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>
        <label title="Нормально" for="star-2"></label>

        <input id="star-1" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>
        <label title="Плохо" for="star-1"></label>

        <input id="star-0" type="radio" name="reviewStars"/>
        <label title="Очень плохо" for="star-0"></label>
```

Велосипед тот выдает значения так: $in{'name'};
Т.е. в $in{'reviewStars'} будет значение "On", если радиокнопка нажата, причем если любая нажата, значение, понятно, будет On.
А мне нужно выцепить значение id из HTML кода выше, т.е. понять какая именно кнопка нажата.
Так:

```
name="reviewStars1"/>
name="reviewStars2"/>
```

сделать не могу, потому что еще CSS прикручен и переделывать его под это - вообще бред получится.

Подскажите как дописать эту CGI-функцию, что бы она видела ID?
Спасибо!
ЗЫ
Велосипед не мой, скрипт тоже, переписать на использование стандартного CGI не предлагать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" id="star-4"
name="reviewStars" value="star-4">
<label title="Замечательно" for="star-4"></label>
```

А так не пробовали?

Comment: Ну конечно же value! Сегодня и проснулся, на свежую голову, с этой мыслью! Спасибо! ))